# HTTP GET file extension support

Tags: sockets, http, get

I discovered HTTP as a nice way to handle my files on my server. I write C programs based on the sockets interface.
When I issue a HTTP GET, I can easily download files, but just files with known extensions. A (backup) file with the extension XXX is "not found" (actually the response return code is 200 ("OK"), but the response content is an HTML page containing the error message (404 = not found).

How can I make sure that the web server sends any file I ask for? I have experimented with the Accept keyword in the HTTP GET request, but that does not help (or I make a mistake).

I do not own the server, so I can not alter the server settings. At the client server, I do not use a browser, only the sockets interface (see above).

Answer (score 3):

I think it is important to understand that HTTP does not really have a concept of "files" and "directories." Instead, the protocol operates on locations and resources. While they *can* represent files and directories, they are absolutely not guaranteed to be the same.

The server in question seems to be configured to serve 404 error pages when encountering unknown extensions. This is a bit weird and absolutely not up to the standard. Though it may happen if a [Web-Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall) is deployed. Again, HTTP does not trust file extensions in any way but relies on metadata in form of [MIME media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) instead. That would also be what goes (more or less) into the `Accept` header of a request.

> How can I make sure that the web server sends any file I ask for?

Well, you can't. While the client may express preferences, the server is the ultimate authority on what gets sent in which way.